# $nth$ derivative of log function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question is , what is nth derivative of $\log(4-x^2)$? I know how to solve general derivatives, but after I encountered with this I am completely bewildered.

Comment: *Hint:* $4 - x^2 = (2-x)(2+x)$.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. It would be best to write down your attempt at solving the problem. Also here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly formatting functions.

Answer (score 2):

For $\ln\lvert 4-x^2\rvert=\ln\lvert x-2\rvert+\ln\lvert x+2\rvert$, the first derivative is
$$\frac1{x-2}+\frac1{x+2},$$
hence an easy induction shows the $n$-th derivative is
$$(-1)^n(n-1)!\biggl(\frac1{(x-2)^n}+\frac1{(x+2)^n}\biggr).$$

Comment: You could show more steps leading to the nth derivative.

Comment: Thank you . But I didn't understand the induction. CAN YOU PLEASE HELP ME

Answer (score 0):

First, one should use the logarithm properties:

> $$ \log(4-x^2) = \log(2 + x) + \log(2 - x)$$

Then, one works on the logarithm derivatives:

> $$D(\log(2 - x)) = -\frac{1}{2-x}, \quad D_2(\log(2-x)) = -\frac{1}{(2-x)^2}$$

and so on.

Then, the solution would be (not 100% sure, calculations done pretty quickly)

> $$ D_n(\log(4-x^2)) = (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{(2+x)^n} -\frac{(n-1)!}{(2-x)^n} $$

Comment: There are no more logarithms after the first derivative.

Comment: Some of your 4s should be 2s.

Comment: Oh my, you're right :-)

Answer (score 0):

As it's said over there:
$$log(4-x^2)=log((x+2)(x-2))=log(x-2)+log(x+2)$$
Then derivate it's simple: taking the first one, for example:
$$ (log(x+2))'= 1/(x+2)$$
Now time to do some calculus, just use the normal derivation rules.
And look, every step, you make the product of the last exponent you got, that's why we use factorial numbers$$$$

the n-esime derivative(without sign): $$(n-1)!/(x+2)^n$$
And make ake some calculus in order to know when it's positive or negative. With this one it's easy, with negative x you must look that negative sign can disappear with the one you obtain derivating $-x$